# Can I specify a field to be used as an `objectId` with parse-server?

Tags: parse-server

Out of the box, parse server adds `objectId` property to every stored [class] object, and sets it to a unique ID. Is it possible to override that, so when I save `person` object, ID would be stored in, let's say, `personFooId` rather than in `objectId`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Parse. You can, as a workaround generate server-side a `personFooId` field on a beforeSave hook on your `Person` class, and setting it as an uuid for example